# ReactJS, functional components. So I want to setState according to whatever <Link> is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-functional-component

For example, I have a list of strains, each strain inside a  component imported from react-router-dom. I want this link to take me to a Route path='/strains/{strain}'. On this page, I want to only render the name of the strain that is clicked, but the names of all of the strains render when one link is clicked. Here is my code showing all of the routes.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserCreation from './components/UserCreation';
import Login from "./components/Login";
import StrainCard from './components/StrainCard';
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import NavBarComponent from "./components/NavBarComponent";
import SavedStrain from './components/SavedStrain';
import Strain from './components/Strain';
import StrainDetails from './components/StrainDetails';

function App() {
  const [strains, setStrains] = useState([]);
  const [savedList, setSavedList] = useState([]);
  const [strain, setStrain] = useState([]);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getStrains = () => {
      axios
        .get('http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/CEIl7eN/strains/search/all')
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          setStrains(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Server Error', error.response);
        });
    }
    getStrains();
  }, []);


console.log(strains)

  useEffect(() => {
    setStrain(Object.keys(strains).slice(0, 20))
  }, [strains])

  console.log(strain)

  const addToSavedList = strain => {
    setSavedList([...savedList, strain]);
  };

  return (
    <Container className="App">
        <NavBarComponent />
      <Route exact path='/'>
        <Link to='/login'>Log in</Link>
      </Route>
        <Route exact path='/login'>
            <Login />
        </Route>
      <Route exact path='/signup'>
        <UserCreation />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path='/strains' render= { () => <StrainCard strains={strains} />} />
      <Route exact path='/strains/:strain' render = {(props) => <StrainDetails {...props} strains={strains} addToSavedList={addToSavedList} strain={strain} />} />
      <Route path='/savedstrains' render={() => <SavedStrain savedList={savedList} /> } />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my code showing how the Links of the strains are rendered.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Card} from 'reactstrap';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
//import SavedStrain from "./SavedStrain";

const Strain = ({strain, strains, type}) => {
    const [filteredStrains, setFilteredStrains] = useState([]);
    
    let x = strains[`${strain}`];
    console.log(x)

    const filterStrains = () => {
        if(x.race === type) {
            setFilteredStrains(strain);
        }
    }

    

    console.log(filteredStrains)

    useEffect(() => {
        filterStrains(); 
    }, [type])

    return (
        <div className='filteredContainer'>
            <Card className='card'>
                <Link to={`/strains/${strain}`}>
                    <div className="strain-card">
                        <div className="strain">
                            {`${filteredStrains}`} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link> 
            </Card> 
        </div>    
    )
}

export default Strain;
```

And finally, here is my code where I want to only display ONE strain depending on what strain Link is clicked on, not all of the strains.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';

const StrainDetails = () => {
    const [strains, setStrains] = useState([]);
    const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
    //const [strain, setStrain] = useState([]);

        
    useEffect(() => {
        const getStrains = () => {
            axios
              .get('http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/CEIl7eN/strains/search/all')
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                setStrains(response.data);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error('Server Error', error.response);
              });
          }
          getStrains();
    }, []);

    console.log(Object.values(strains).slice(0, 20))

    useEffect(() => {
        setDetails(Object.values(strains).slice(0, 20));
    }, [strains])

    console.log(details);

    let strain = Object.keys(strains).slice(0, 20).map(y => {return y});
    let x = Object.keys(strains).slice(0,20);

    // const addToSavedList = strain => {
    //     setSavedList([...savedList, strain]);
    //     console.log(savedList);
    //   };
    
    // const saveStrain = () => {
    //     addToSavedList(strain);
    // }

    return (
            <div className='container'>
                <Card>
                    <div className="strain-card">
                        <div className='name'>
                            strain: {strain}
                        </div>
                        {/* <div className='id'>
                            ID: {x.id.toString()}
                        </div>
                        <div className='type'>
                            Type: {x.race.toString()}
                        </div>
                        <div className='flavors'>
                            Flavors: {x.flavors.toString()}
                        </div>
                        <div className='effects'>
                            Medical effects: {x.effects.medical.toString()} <br />
                            Positive effects: {x.effects.positive.toString()} <br />
                            Negative effects: {x.effects.negative.toString()} <br />
                        </div> */}
                        {/* <Button className='save' onClick={saveStrain}>Save</Button> */}
                    </div>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default StrainDetails;
```

For example, I want only the strain Alien Bubba to show up, not all of the strains. (I clicked the Link Alien Bubba)

[image of what happens when one link is clicked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlgrL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is, a way to access the route params(strain in your case), pass the router props to your component in the render callback like this

```
<Route exact path='/strains/:strain' render = {(props) => <Strain {...props} strains={strains} addToSavedList={addToSavedList} />} />
```

Now in your Strain component, you can access the params like this

```
const Strain = ({match}) => {
   console.log(match.params)
}
```